# Async function running before completion of rest of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

Below is the node.jscode to read content of a file

```
let { readFile, WriteFile } = require('fs')


let create = (path) => {
    console.log("Inside function")
    return new Promise((resole, reject) => {
        readFile(path, 'utf-8', (err, ifo) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err)
            if (ifo)
                resole(ifo)

        })
    }

    )
}

const start = async () => {

    console.log("1")
    const content = await create("./Series.txt");   // Series.txt file contains word TRICK
    console.log(content)
    console.log("2")
}


start();
console.log("Me first")
```

Now I read that Event loop moves out the asynchronous  code from stack to WebAPIs and after rest of the code is executed or stack is empty then the asynchronous code is again bought to the stack.
Therefore my expectation of output was

```
Me first
1
Inside function
TRICK
2
```

However the output I am getting is

```
1
Inside function
Me first
TRICK
2
```

Can someone please explain me that if entire function `start` is asynchronous and would be moved from stack then why and how `1` and `Inside function` is being printed first ?

Comment: You have misunderstood whatever you read. It's not the whole function that's "moved from stack", it's the asynchronous operations. Until execution gets to the `await` inside `start()`, it's all synchronous.

Comment: Your function `start()` returns a promise at the moment the execution his `await create()` and you are not awaiting that promise so executing continues beyond that and does not wait for `start()` to finish.  ALL `async` function return a promise.  If you want to wait for them to be done, you must `await` that promise.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you look at `fs.promises.readFile()` and `fs.promises.writeFile()` since they are already promisified versions.